# During running mlt command with different videos getting bitrate issues?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, video-editing

I'm running melt command to edit some video clips and audio clips. I'm giving here the command which I'm using to get edited video but getting issue with bit rate as well as it's taking too much time to execute this command. I've latest version of MLT(0.8.0) and installed in UBUNTU.
The command are as below:

```
    melt  avformat:http://54.241.13.15/cdn/images/1/1576/17s_331.flv  out=425.4 -move in=0  out=425.4  out=425.4  -track  avformat:http://54.241.13.15/cdn/image/1/1584 /180_834.flv  out=336.9 -move in=0  out=336.9  out=336.9 -filter chroma key=#00ff00 variance=0.38 -transition composite geometry="42%,24%,50%,50%" halign=left valign=top  a_track=0 b_track=1  -track  -blank 61.2  a_track=0 b_track=2  avformat:http://54.241.13.15/cdn/images/1/1583/17z_786.flv  out=398.1 -move in=0  out=336.9  out=398.1 -filter chroma key=#00FF00 variance=0.38 -transition composite geometry="14%,10%,38%,43%" halign=left valign=top  a_track=0 b_track=2  -track  avformat:http://54.241.13.15/cdn/images/1/1532/16k_177.mp3  out=756.9 -move in=0  out=756.9  out=756.9  composite.progressive=1 producer.align=center  -consumer avformat:/var/www/enclood/app/web/files/test-temp1.webm s=320x240 fullscreen=1 rescale=bilinear frequency=22050 b=512k ab=128k  -profile square_ntsc vcodec=libtheora b=1000k ab=512k f=ogg | oggfwd 127.0.0.1 8000 manu123 /live.ogg
```

Output taking too much time and getting following issues:

```
    [flv @ 0xb9643940] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
    [flv @ 0xb9643940] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
    [mp3 @ 0xb0998cc0] max_analyze_duration reached
```

How to fix this issue?

Please respond me. Thanks in advance!